# Vertex Texture Fetch always return 0

Tags: directx-11, vertex-shader, terrain

I'm developing a shader based terrain. Use VTF to fetch the height data in vertex shader. My problem is when I sample heightmap in vertex shader the returned value always is zero.

```
Texture2D texture;
SamplerState sampleType;
float height = texture.SampleLevel(sampleType, float4(input.tex, 0, 0), 0);
```

The texture loaded from BMP file (256x256x24bit) with D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile(device, heightmap, NULL, NULL, &texture) function and passed to vertex shader with deviceContext->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &texture). Feature level is D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0 and shader profile is vs_4_0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling deviceContext->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &texture),

which means you pass the texture to the pixel shader.
You need to bind texture and sampler to the vertex shader instead, using

[VSSetSamplers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476492%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
and
[VSSetShaderResources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

instead.